# WMI query ran in a Powershell console yields less results in 32 bits mode than 64 bits mode

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

This query `gwmi -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory` gives fewer results if I run it in a 32 bits PowerShell console than in a 64 bits one. 
It looks like background processes, like services, are the ones only showing up in 64 bits. This isn't unique to PowerShell, I'm getting the same inconsistent results in both C# and F#. I'm also getting the issue in some monitoring tooling I use.

What is happening here? How do I make the 32 bits mode work correctly?

Comment: Define 'correctly'?  Wouldn't the 32 bit version give you data on **only** 32 bit processes, and the 64 bit version give you info on 64+32 bit processes?  Why would you expect the 32 bit mode to be able to report on 64 bit processes?

Comment: As far as I know data is stored at the same place for both 32 and 64 bits processes in WMI so I don't know why it would make a difference being in either 32 or 64 bits mode.

Comment: You need to setup [_Context Flags_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27722538/3439404), particularly `__ProviderArchitecture` (64 or 32) and `__RequiredArchitecture` flags. See [Accessing Default and Nondefault Provider Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390789(v=vs.85).aspx) and `powershell` solution [here (another class but the same approach)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130808/3439404).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adopted [JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608772/jpblanc)'s solution from [this answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130808/3439404)

```
# Setup the context information
$mContext = New-Object System.Management.ManagementNamedValueCollection
$mContext.Add( "__ProviderArchitecture", 64)
$mContext.Add( "__RequiredArchitecture", $true)

# Setup the Authrntification object
$ConOptions = New-Object System.Management.ConnectionOptions
#$ConOptions.Username = "computername\administrateur" # Should be used for remote access
#$ConOptions.Password = "toto"
$ConOptions.EnablePrivileges = $true
$ConOptions.Impersonation = "Impersonate"
$ConOptions.Authentication = "Default"
$ConOptions.Context = $mContext

# Setup the management scope (change with the computer name for remote access)
$mScope = New-Object System.Management.ManagementScope( `
                                "\\localhost\root\cimV2", $ConOptions)

$mScope.Connect()

# Query
$queryString = "SELECT * From Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory"
$oQuery = New-Object System.Management.ObjectQuery ($queryString)
$oSearcher = New-Object System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher ($mScope, $oQuery)
$oResult = $oSearcher.Get();

$oResult.Name      # only for simple check that current code snippet gives 
                   # the same results from both 32 and 64 -bit version of PowerShell
```

> ### [Requesting WMI Data on a 64-bit Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> By default, an application or script receives data from the
>   corresponding provider when two versions of providers exist. The
>   32-bit provider returns data to a 32-bit application, including all
>   scripts, and the 64-bit provider returns data to the 64-bit compiled
>   applications. However, an application or script can request data from
>   the nondefault provider, if it exists, by notifying WMI through flags
>   on method calls.
>
> **Context Flags** The `__ProviderArchitecture` and `__RequiredArchitecture` string flags have a set of values handled by
>   WMI but not defined in SDK header or type library files. The values
>   are placed in a context parameter to signal WMI that it should request
>   data from the nondefault provider. 
> The following lists the flags
>   and their possible values.
>
> - `__ProviderArchitecture` Integer value, either 32 or 64, that specifies the 32-bit or 64-bit version.
> - `__RequiredArchitecture` Boolean value used in addition to `__ProviderArchitecture` to force load the specified provider version.
>     If the version is unavailable, then WMI returns the error
>     `0x80041013`, `wbemErrProviderLoadFailure` for Visual Basic and
>     `WBEM_E_PROVIDER_LOAD_FAILURE` for C++. The default value for this
>     flag when it is not specified is `FALSE`.
>
> On a 64-bit system that has side-by-side versions of a provider, a
>   32-bit application or script automatically receives data from the
>   32-bit provider, unless these flags are supplied and indicate that the
>   64-bit provider data should be returned.